# Add multiple solutions referencing the same projects to SourceSafe?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I've replaced someone at this company, and he was their SourceSafe guy. He kind of sucked at it, but he knew more than anyone else (i.e. anything at all) and so I'm kind of stuck for places to ask this question. Sorry.

Anyway, I've got a StartUp project (StartupProjectA) in Visual Studio that references projects A, B and C. I've got all of those in SolutionA.

My predecessor has previously added this solution to SourceSafe so that there's a SolutionA folder in SourceSafe, containing a StartupProjectA folder, and A folder, a B folder and a C folder.

It turns out, though, that StartupProjectB and StartupProjectC all live in the same directory as StartupProjectA on the local machine, so on the PC I'm using I have a [GeneralSolution] folder which contains a StartupProjectA folder, a StartupProjectB folder, a StartupProjectC folder, and A folder, a B folder and a C folder.

My question is what do I do to get the Solutions for StartupProjectB and StartupProjectC into SourceSafe? I've tried adding them, but they all create their own copies of folders A, B and C. What have I missed?

EDIT: Based on Gabriel's answer:

I'm trying to use the Visual Studio SourceSafe integration to get these solutions into SourceSafe. Doing so creates multiple redundant copies of A, B and C. I would like to have one folder in SourceSafe, containing SPA, SPB, SPC, A, B and C folders. I'm not really sure how to do this, because I can only add entire Solutions to SourceSafe via Visual Studio. There's no option that I can see for "Add this folder to SourceSafe and recognise that these other three folders are already referenced in the repository and so don't need to be added."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open StartupProjectB, before adding the solution to sourcesafe, go to File > Source Control > Change Source Control

You should then be able to select each project in the Solution and manually bind it to the project in SourceSafe.

Once done, you should be able to add the Solution to SourceSafe and only the projects that are not already in SS will be added.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason those solutions can't be in the same folder?  I usually match the folder structure on the client and in source control.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm trying to add these all through Visual Studio's SourceSafe integration, and it's what's putting them all in different folders. I'm trying to get them all into the same folder. I'll edit my question a bit to make this more clear.

Comment: For something like this, I wouldn't do it VIA Visual Studio Integration.  I would use the SourceSafe UI.  Its been a while since I used VSS, so I don't remember the steps.  Basically, though, use their UI to add the solution files to the same folder.

Comment: Right, I've added the files to SourceSafe, moved from the old guy's old machine back to my machine, gotten the latest version of SolutionB from SourceSafe, and for some insane reason it's telling me that StartupProjectB isn't under version control, even though I got the files out of the repository. I would guess that even though the files themselves are under version control, SolutionB as a whole isn't a Visual Studio/SourceSafe entity. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Remove Bindings and re-add them.  I think this is under File/Source Control/Change Source Control.  In the dialog, highlight the solution, and click Unbind (unless it already is unbound).  Then highlight it again and click Bind.  It will either autmatically bind it correctly or allow you to browse to it.

Answer (score 0):

after adding StartupProjectB to SourceSafe using its UI, open the solution via File->Source Control->Open from Source Control in Visual Studio. This should establish the binding.